# how to consider just first element in arrays

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I've the follwing items in a collection:

> { "_id":1, "vals": [ { a:1, b:2, c:0 }, { a:1, b:2, c:1 }, { a:1, b:2, c:2 } ] }
>   { "_id":2, "vals": [ { a:1, b:2, c:1 }, { a:1, b:2, c:2 }, { a:1, b:2, c:0 } ] }
>   { "_id":3, "vals": [ { a:1, b:2, c:2 }, { a:1, b:2, c:0 }, { a:1, b:2, c:1 } ] }

I want to find all item with ( vals.c > 1 ), but only considering always the first element in array.
Doing that in the right way I would get only items: _id:2, _id:3 in the result.

Taking the follwing find-request I get all items instead.

> db.items.find( { vals: { $elemMatch: { c: { $gte:1 } } }, { "vals.$": 1 } } )

Any idea how to make the request, to get the wished result?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps surprisingly, you can do it like so:

```
db.items.find({ 'vals.0.c': { $gte: 1 } })
```

You can choose to return only the zeroeth array element in your query results with the $slice query-projection operator:

```
db.items.find({ 'vals.0.c': { $gte: 1 } }, {'vals': {'$slice': 1}})
```

See [$slice](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/slice/), and you may also be interested in the new [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/elemMatch/) projection operator.

Comment: Yep! You're right! Til yesterday evening I didn't know about index-usage while accessing array-fields. Thanx!

Comment: Do you know by purechange how I can reduce the resultset just by matching? In example I get all three array-items.  I tried using $(query) and $(projection)-operator, but it's unfortunatelly not allowed then to access array-fields by index. =(